# Trying the if statement to get the exordium right bij text that's in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am a newbe when it comes to Excel VBA, but...

For my job, I'm trying to get letter templates automated with data from Excel.
What I'm trying to achieve, is to get the right exordium. When I don't use the if statement, it will get it right, but then I have to change by hand the right exordium if it changes gender.

Code example:

```
.Application.Selection.Find.Text = "heer, mevrouw,"
.Application.Selection.Find.Execute
.Application.Selection.Font.Color = vbBlack
.Application.Selection.TypeText "mevrouw" & Range("D4").Value & ","
.Application.Selection.Move
```

This works, only when cell C4 contains "mevrouw".
I have to change the code manually when cell C4 contans "de heer":

```
.Application.Selection.Find.Text = "heer, mevrouw,"
.Application.Selection.Find.Execute
.Application.Selection.Font.Color = vbBlack
.Application.Selection.TypeText "heer" & Range("D4").Value & ","
.Application.Selection.Move
```

I've tried to use an IF statement, but I can't get it done.
Any help would be appreciated.

Code examle:

```
.Application.Selection.Find.Text = "heer, mevrouw,"
.Application.Selection.Find.Execute
.Application.Selection.Font.Color = vbBlack

If .Application.Selection = ActiveSheet.Range("C4").Value = "mevrouw" Then
   .Application.Selection.TypeText "mevrouw" & Range("D4").Value & ","

ElseIf .Application.Selection = ActiveSheet.Range("C4").Value = "de heer" Then
       .Application.Selection.TypeText "heer" & Range("D4").Value & ","

end if
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: Anyone who can help me out?

Comment: I was able to fix it myself. I had to use an Instr. function combined with an IF statement.